# getting query parameter on initial route flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, web, routes, query-string

I'm working on a flutter application mainly for the web, and I'm unable to add/get the query
parameter from the URL, the query parameter will contain an id, and this id should be used inside the app

this my route setup on my app state:

```
  return MaterialApp(navigatorKey: key,  initialRoute: '/main',
        routes: {
          // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
          '/main': (context) => Map_View(),
          // When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen widget.
          '/second': (context) => TaskClosed(),
        },onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,);
  }


  class RouteGenerator{
    
      static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings){
        final args = settings.arguments;
        print(args);
        var routingData = settings.name;
      }}
```

the settings.arguments are always null

so what should I pass to initialRoute to make it accept arguments on the first screen
for example, the calling URL should be  like this:

https:example.com/main?123

so how to get this parameter from the URL

Comment: Use something like this `Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second', arguments: 'https:example.com/main?123')`

Comment: the parameter should be received from the url on the initial route generator and not within the app

Comment: check this out: https://sellsbrothers.com/understanding-flutter-deep-links-on-the-web

Comment: See [qlevar_router](https://github.com/SchabanBo/qlevar_router#query-param), form the [example](https://qlevar-router.netlify.app) go to `params/:id` you will get the id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this code:

```
class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    String? route;
    Map? queryParameters;
    if (settings.name != null) {
      var uriData = Uri.parse(settings.name!);
      route = uriData.path;
      queryParameters = uriData.queryParameters;
    }
    var message =
        'generateRoute: Route $route, QueryParameters $queryParameters';
    print(message);
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        return MyHomePage(title: message);
      },
      settings: settings,
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/main',
      routes: {
        // '/': (context) {
        //   print('route: /');
        //   return MyHomePage(title: 'Home');
        // },
        '/main': (context) {
          print('route: /main');
          return MyHomePage(title: 'route: Main');
        },
        '/second': (context) {
          print('route: /second');
          return MyHomePage(title: 'route: Second');
        },
      },
      onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
    );
  }
}
```

When I run the app with the URL `http://localhost:55260/#/main?123`, I get this output:

```
generateRoute: Route /, QueryParameters {}
generateRoute: Route /main, QueryParameters {123: }
```

The screen is displayed for `/main` and the URL is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I misunderstand the scenario. Here is my suggest

remove `routes`

```
  return MaterialApp(navigatorKey: key,  initialRoute: '/main',
        //routes: {
          // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
          //'/main': (context) => Map_View(),
          // When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen widget.
          //'/second': (context) => TaskClosed(),
          // },
       onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,);
  }
```

And change like

```
class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    final args = settings.arguments;
    print(args);
    var routingData = settings.name;
    switch (routingData) {
      case "/main":
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return Map_View();
          },
          settings: settings,
        );
        break;
      case "/second":
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return TaskClosed();
          },
          settings: settings,
        );
        break;
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return YouUnKnowPage();
          },
          settings: settings,
        );
    }
  }
}
```

when you call `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/main",arguments:"123");`
It will move to `TaskClosed` and print `123` in the console

Furthermore, if you directly type the link like `https:example.com/main?123`
It will lead to `YouUnKnowPage` instead of `Map_View` and the arguments will be `null`. Try to use `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/main",arguments:"123");`

If you insist on directly type the link, you can try this

```
class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
      String routingData;
      var arguments;
      if (settings.name != null) {
          routingData = settings.name;
      }
      final args = settings.arguments;

      if (args != null) {
          arguments = args;
      } else {
          Uri settingsUri = Uri.parse(settings.name);
          if (settingsUri.hasQuery) {
            arguments = "${settingsUri.queryParameters}";
          }
          if (settingsUri.pathSegments.length > 1) {
          routingData =
             "/" + settingsUri.pathSegments[settingsUri.pathSegments.length - 1];
          }
      }
    if (arguments != null) {
      print(arguments);
    }
     switch (routingData) {
      case "/main":
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return Map_View();
          },
          settings: settings,
        );
        break;
      case "/second":
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return TaskClosed();
          },
          settings: settings,
        );
        break;
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return YouUnKnowPage();
          },
          settings: settings,
        );
    }
  }
}
```

Now it will move to `TaskClosed` and print `{123:}` in the console

Comment: yes I tried this way and I can get the URL and the query parameter but it will not be shown on the URL and it will not be received after reloading the page, I think there should be a way to receive it from the RouteGenerator on initialroute

Comment: that's not an actual answer